# SQL Column with Variable Table Value

Tags: sql, reportbuilder

I am trying to write a report that has multiple sub tables with similar values in the FROM portion of the report. Many of the tables will have a null value. The report needs to have a column1 with a value from the first table where the value is not null, column2 with a value from the second table that is not null and so forth. I have considered using case statements, but I think it would either duplicate the values or leave values out. I already have the report written where the table values show column for column in the report:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
table.column1,    
table.column2,    
table.column3,     
V1.column1,
V1.column2,
V1.column3,  
V1.column4,    
V1.column5,
  ...repeat for each V2, V3, V4 so on to more than 20
      
FROM table 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT a.column1, a.column2 , a.column3 , a.column4, b.column1 AS column5  
FROM table_1 as a JOIN table_2 as b ON a.value = b.value WHERE a.value = 'V1') AS V1     
ON table.value = V1.value
...repeat for each V2, V3, V4 so on to more than 20
```

But this is not sufficient. Neither is concatenating the values into one column.

As another snag, this has to be processed through report builder, so there is a character limit.

Help with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ISNULL() function. In the below query, the ISNULL() function checks as individual comumn and if it is NULL, it replaces it with ''.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(table.column1,'') + ISNULL(table.column2,'') +...      
FROM table 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT a.column1, a.column2 , a.column3 , a.column4, b.column1 AS column5  
FROM table_1 as a JOIN table_2 as b ON a.value = b.value WHERE a.value = 'V1') AS V1     
ON table.value = V1.value
...repeat for each V2, V3, V4 so on to more than 20
```

I hope this'll be useful to you.

Obs.: if '+' is not working, use ' || '
OR

CONCAT ( ISNULL(table.column1,''), ISNULL(table.column2,'') …ISNULL(table.columnN,'') ] )

Comment: I wish this would be sufficient... But I've been told specifically that a concat of the data into one column is not.

Comment: I've thought about defining each column, like this: delcare '@column varchar(100) '@column2 varchar(100) select '@column=CASE WHEN THEN END, '@column2= case when <> '@column THEN END I feel like this isn't very clear... but I don't think this will work because of my character length issue